# Diferença no uso da '/' e '\' ao definir um caminho no diretório

Tags: python, string, diretório, path

Eu estava montando um código que se utiliza de leitura e escrita de arquivos (`.txt` e `.csv`) em Python e ao copiar o caminho pelo explorador de arquivos, me deparei com o caso onde ele copiou um dos caminhos com `/` e outro com `\`.

Ao tentar executar o código, ele deu erro por estar usando `/` simples, então usei `//` e `\\` e ele rodou corretamente. Mas isso me deixou confuso numa coisa, qual a diferença no uso da `\` e `/` e o que elas diferem de `//` e `\\` ao se definir um caminho de diretório em um programa?

```
arquivo = "C:\\Users\\henrique\\Desktop\\py\\arquvio.txt"    #Rodou no código
arquivo = "C://Users//henrique//Desktop//py//arquvio.txt"    #Rodou no código
arquivo = "C:/Users/henrique/Desktop/py/arquvio.txt"         #Rodou no código
arquivo = "C:\Users\henrique\Desktop\py\arquvio.txt"         #Não rodou no código
file = open(arquivo, 'w+', encoding='utf-8')
file.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Linux usa o `/` como separador do caminho de arquivos e diretórios. O Windows já usa `\`.

Como Python escolheu usar a barra invertida como caractere de escape, ou seja, o que vem a seguir deve ter um tratamento especial, esse caractere não pode ser usada de forma normal como um caractere comum. Mas ela pode escapar ela mesma, então uma dupla barra faz com que ao que vem a seguir, outra barra invertida, seja considerado um caractere normal. Por isso um não funcionou.

Como parece estar rodando no Windows então funcionará o `\\`.

Se usar a *string* bruta onde a barra invertida não tem funcionalidade especial também funciona:

```
arquivo = r"C:\Users\henrique\Desktop\py\arquvio.txt"
```

O Python trata a barra normal no Windows de forma correta também.

O ideal é usar o [`os.pathsep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pathsep) para garantir que o sistema rode bem em qualquer sistema operacional. Pelo menos para um caso assim. Pode ser necessário outros cuidados em toda aplicação para rodar bem em todos OSs.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).